# Could a steel beam span 24 feet for a pergola?

Tags: pergola

First time post here, thank you for such a great resource! I've done a lot of research but am hoping I can get some help building a pretty large pergola.

I'm trying to be my own master contractor and hire subcontractors to build a long freestanding pergola with no post in the middle. My plan is to have an architect draw up plans, but before I started spending money I'm trying to see if this is even a viable project that a pretty handy person can manage. Basically am I crazy for attempting this?

Property details
- main structure is a duplex 
- there is a detached four car carport/garage 12' from the back of the main structure. 
- trying to cover the space between the garage and the house with a slight hang over both structures.

Project details:
- 24' L x 14' W. 
- I am hoping that a steel beam could span the length with no post. 
    a) What's the max length span? It would be preferable to go greater than 24'L.
    b) Any guesstimates on what a beam this size would weigh?
- Would 8" x 8" wood post be strong enough?
    a) how deep do footings need to go and how close can footing be to house foundation?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A diagram of exactly what you're hoping to do would really help us. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Welcome, Luke. You'e asked several distinct questions here. We're not a discussion forum. Please do take the tour Daniel suggested and then revise your post to just ask one clear thing. Post other questions if you like.

Comment: Is the 24' length parallel to the existing structures?   Could it be supported by the buildings?  (This is non-trivial, as you'd have to go right through the cladding into the  studs or beams of the house)

Comment: Thank you for the tour recommendation. Now that I know how the site works a little better I think I can search it a little better. 

Chris- I was trying to avoid attaching it to the house, just because I don't want to go through the brick and a roofer advised against using roof risers on the roof.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with an architect.

Hire a structural engineer if anyone.

You want a 24' long beam, probably two?  with just some minimal loading from open air beams that sit on the two 24'L beams?  A quick diagram would help.

24' is long but I've done wood PSLs 5.25"x11.75" that open air span more than that and support floor and roof loads.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I'm going to research the site a little better for my specific problems and then maybe come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a good plan

Steel can span hundreds of feet: they use it to make bridges and other large structures.

You can probably meet your goal with a cold formed steel beams (the cheapest kind of steel)

You can either consult a structural engineer or use a framing handbook to determine the sizes of the structural members and footings needed for your project in your location.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider an "engineered wood " beam ; several 2 X 6 or 2 X 8 ,etc, glued together like plywood. I have commonly seen these in modern ( since about 1960) churches . Although often on a angle they are longer than 50 ft. For steel you need to have transitions between steel and wood.  Of course a steel beam would be much smaller than laminated wood.